# Is there any paper introduce an intuitive method for clustering evaluation?

Tags: clustering, distance

I would like to use the most intuitive method like minimizing the within-cluster distance and maximizing the distance between neighbouring clusters, but not sure does this method have a name or something? Is there any related paper regarding it? The only method I'm using now is Silhouette score. Many thanks.

Comment: It's not clear if your question is about clustering evaluation or clustering methods? For proper evaluation one needs annotated data and/or a task-specific method to measure the quality of the clusters.

Comment: What is wrong with Silhouette? It is too intuitive and too little mathematically based in my opinion, I would have defined it differently...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Hi thanks for the reply, nothing's wrong with it, just want to know if there is any other evaluating method. In terms of Silhouette, I followed this tutorial:https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html, but I'm a bit confused about the concept, is it only consider the distance between one point and neighbouring clusters, so the score is the higher the better What about the within cluster distance which we want it the smaller the betterʔ

Comment: Silhouette uses both distances and scores high if they differ, i.e. within << to next other cluster. Make sure you understand the a and b terms.

Comment: Thanks @Anony-Mousse